i18n with Static Export Build in Next.js
I am building a website for my company using Next.js. But I have to deploy it using output: export in my next.config.mjs. The requirement is to implement i18n with the static export build of my app. I've been looking for solutions online but couldn't find the one that can fulfill the following requirements:

Dynamically Update the lang and dir attributes in the top level <html> tag.
Provides locale in getStaticProps().

I want to support en, ar and fr languages and ar is an RTL language. If I cannot access the locales in my pages dynamically then i cannot implement the correct hrefLang tags in my pages and also if the lang and dir tags don't update dynamically in my top level <html> tag then RTL won't work with ar. I also want to avoid hydration errors.
Please help.
